# Force a mobile device to scan available wifi network by manually flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, wifi, settings, scanning

I need to get information from a Wifi SSID (without connecting to any wifi network) as a string. I tried many packages like wifi_iot,wifi_hunter,wifi_configuration_2 etc. None of those packages refresh available wifi list fast enough. I need to force wifi scan rate to higher. Is there any way to change refresh rate using flutter ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.